# Watching function return from service not working but a scope function works

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

i have a problem with a service function.

If i use a function in a view through a service it wouldnt updated if the return changes.

But if i use a function which is declared in controller it works.

**Why?**

First example, not working, service function:

https://jsfiddle.net/xrzr457v/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []),
    test = null;

myApp.factory('myService', function() {
    return {
        checkLoggedIn: function()
        {
            return test == null;
        }
    }
});

function MyCtrl($scope, myService)
{
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.service = myService;
    $scope.LoginTxt = 'Login';
    $scope.login = function()
    {
        $scope.LoginTxt = 'You should be logged in and the texts should be moved!';
        test = true;
    };
}
```

Second example, working, controller function:

https://jsfiddle.net/t3nyejLy/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []),
    test = null;

function MyCtrl($scope)
{
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.checkLoggedIn = function()
    {
        return test == null;
    };
    $scope.LoginTxt = 'Login';
    $scope.login = function()
    {
        $scope.LoginTxt = 'You should be logged out and the texts should be moved!';
        test = true;
    };
}
```

**Thanks for any idea!**

Comment: Why `$service` instead if just `service` in your template? you called it `service` in your controller. (you should include the templates in your question since they're important to solving this problem.)

Comment: I think i must use $ before the service in the template. But if i try what you said it works -.- :D Interesting! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if i remove the $ in front of the variable.

https://jsfiddle.net/xrzr457v/2/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []),
    test = null;

myApp.factory('myService', function() {
    return {
        checkLoggedIn: function()
        {
            return test == null;
        }
    }
});

function MyCtrl($scope, myService)
{
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.service = myService;
    $scope.LoginTxt = 'Login';
    $scope.login = function()
    {
        $scope.LoginTxt = 'You should be logged in and the texts should be moved!';
        test = true;
    };
}
```

and template

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    Hello, {{name}}!<br />
    You're logged
    <p ng-show="service.checkLoggedIn()">in</p>
    <p ng-hide="service.checkLoggedIn()">out</p>
    .
    <br /><br />
    <button ng-click="login()" ng-show="service.checkLoggedIn()">{{ LoginTxt }}</button>
</div>
```

It's very interesting to learn AngularJS syntax :)

Thanks [Kevin B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400654/kevin-b).